# Why does my MCU work better when powered to Vcc and PA1=D2 instead of Vcc and GND?

Tags: microcontroller, power, ground, attiny, midi

I'm making a MIDI processor, with its power coming ... directly from the MIDI signal itself, as done by the author of [this page](https://mitxela.com/projects/midi_on_the_attiny) (see "Powered by MIDI" paragraph): it works well with a 100µF cap. I have assembled several units with no problem at all, perfectly working.

I'm using a ATtiny4313 and usually it's wired this way:

- VCC (pin 20) => + of the 100 µF cap
- GND (pin 10) => GND of MIDI sockets
- RX/D0 (pin 2) => MIDI IN (with the usual MIDI IN schematics involving an optocoupler and resistors)
- TX/D1 (pin 3) => MIDI OUT (with the usual MIDI OUT schematics too)

However **on new units I'm currently assembling I noticed that it is *not* working very well** (sometimes the MIDI signal is ok, sometimes it's not ok, and some notes are stuck, some are dropped).

Then, instead of the previous connection, I tried this way:

- VCC (pin 20) => + of the 100 µF cap
- **PA1/D2 (pin 4) => GND of MIDI sockets**
- RX/D0 (pin 2) => MIDI IN (with the usual MIDI IN schematics involving an optocoupler and resistors)
- TX/D1 (pin 3) => MIDI OUT (with the usual MIDI OUT schematics too)
- and nothing connected to GND of the ATtiny!

And miracuously, everything works perfectly, the MIDI signal is perfect, no lost or stuck note! I tried it during a long time and it's perfect like this.

**Question: What could be the reason of this thing: the MCU works better when powered on VCC (pin 20) and PA1/D2 (pin 4), instead of VCC and GND?**

[image]

PS: In my code, I did nothing with pin #4, no `digitalWrite`, no `pinMode`. The only thing present in my code relative to a pin is `pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);`, because I might add a push button later.

PS2: I thought it would be a oscillator problem with the internal oscillator a little bit too much "off" and that adding a crystal would solve it, but then **why would doing `PA1/D2 (pin 4) ==> GND` solve everything perfectly well**, even without a crystal?

PS3: I read a few parts of the [ATtiny 4313 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8246.pdf) without any clue about this mysterious situation, i.e. power it in an uncommon way and it works 100%!

Comment: Please draw a schematic. Powering microcontrollers via data pins is very suspicious. Also if you are not aware MIDI devices are not meant to be powered from MIDI, that is not how a MIDI IN device should work according to MIDI examples, it only works if the MIDI out device is also made according to MIDI examples. So if you make a weird device, and connect it to device that is also weird, it just does not have to work..

Comment: You are decoupling with a 100µF cap? Electrolytic? Is there some smaller ceramic somewhere?

Comment: @dim Just an electrolytic 100µF cap, no smaller ceramic. I might try to add a smaller ceramic, but again this wouldn't explain it works perfectly well when PA1/D2 (pin 4) is connected to GND instead of pin 10. What a mystery!

Comment: @Justme Many very well-known-in-every-studio and perfectly-working MIDI processors are powered via MIDI *only*, see for example this one from a good brand: https://www.thomann.de/gb/midi_solutions_merger_v2.htm

Comment: @Justme See also the reviews for such products, I've never seen anyone complain about the powered-by-MIDI thing in a review, it just works for everyone, with I think nearly all synthesizers (all the ones I have at least, and given all the review I have read, all synthesizers that people tried it with).

Comment: Well, not having a ~100n ceramic could certainly explain why it works erratically. You really should try that first. Now, I can explain why it still gets powered with GND through the PA1 pin: that's thanks to the protection diode. But I can't say why it works better that way.

Comment: @dim Can you elaborate about why it gets powered with GND through the PA1 pin and protection diode in an answer maybe? This would solve 50% of the mystery at least!

Comment: @Basj reviews are product marketing garbage, of course the ones with "does not work for me" reviews get deleted or not submitted anyway. The cheap chinese USB to MIDI interfaces that have no optoisolator tend to work quite poorly.

Comment: @Justme Please believe me about this, I've seen these devices (they are *not* USB to MIDI interfaces ; btw I have many Chinese cheap USB to MIDI devices but that's another story) in many many studios, and they are recognized as good products. Also the supplier I linked (I'll remove the link later to avoid advertisement effect) is quite good (ask any musician in Europe), and the reviews are usually trustful, at least ten times more than on other platforms.

Comment: @Justme Also, these units are designed in Canada by people knowing what they're doing (I'll remove this comment later to avoid advert: http://midisolutions.com/about.htm). So please don't consider that "what they design is bad" randomly without knowing the product ;) TL;DR It's not a 1$ chinese product, but a good engineered product, please beleive me.

Comment: @dim Do you think the reason could be what I explained in my PS? i.e. having PB7 in internal pullup (`pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);`) might draw too much current for this MIDI powered system? And then if I "power" the MCU via I/O pin, the PB7 internal would be bypassed? (Why?) Could this be the reason?

Comment: @Basj Oh they know very well what they are doing, and they are doing it on purpose. On their website FAQ they even acknowledge it may or may not work depending on the situation and device. I know MIDI enough that I know it is not made according to the spirit of MIDI specification and it may work under certain circumstances and with devices that are designed in certain way which happens to be the most common way. Please also understand that it does not work in all circumstances and devices designed in other ways which are made according to MIDI specification.

Comment: @Basj on the contrary, most likely it does not work because internal pull-up is too weak so and you might be better off with an external pull-up between UART RXD and VCC. The MIDI output could be open-collector type so rising edge with internal pull-up only could be too slow for it to work.

Comment: @Justme Interesting, I'll investigate this! Thanks for your help and time spent on this topic by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Powering it via IO pin protection diode would make the GND to be a diode drop higher than the IO pin voltage. It might work better because of how different devices have different MIDI OUT buffers, not all MIDI OUT interfaces are alike, some are driven with push-pull output drivers, some are driven with open-drain outputs.

[image]

(Source: datasheet)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How is connected this protection diode (which kind of diode?) between PA1/D2 and what?

Comment: Please open your AVR datasheet about IO pin structure which shows internal protection diodes from IO pin to GND and VCC.

Comment: Ok I'm looking this, thanks @Justme!

Comment: @Basj Look at the first picture [there](https://wisense.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/interfacing-safely-with-the-msp430/) for example. For each GPIO, there are two diodes: one diverting any excess voltage to VCC and another diverting any excess negative voltage to GND. So you could power the MCU through those diodes, even though that's not recommended. See [this project](https://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/) for a stunning example.

Comment: @Justme I edited and added the schematic found in the datasheet for future reference, I hope it's ok for you.

Comment: Could the also reason be that each I/O pin is connect to a GND via a capacitor C_pin? (I don't know the actual value btw)

Comment: That is not a deliberate capacitor, it is stray pin capacitance formed by the wiring and structures on silicon die, case, etc.